# Как исправить проблему в modal-backdrop fade show

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Проблема такая: `http://inkomtrade.ooo/novosti.html`
это тестовая страница со своими стилями (убрал лишние блоки, но стили оставил, ибо они такие и будут в будущем) и с формой обратной связи. Форма работает, инфа приходит на почту. Но после нажатия кнопки "отправить" остается серый фон у `<div class="modal-backdrop fade show"></div>`
Никак не могу понять, что фону не дает исчезнуть, как например на главной странице: `http://inkomtrade.ooo` (повторюсь у этих двух страниц разные стили) и требуется решение конкретно под стили страницы "новости".
Спасибо заранее!
p.s. можете завалить почту отправленными формами, я не обижусь)

Comment: /При клике отправить уберите класс show с вашего backdrop , а лучше покажите ваш код что попытались сделать и что не получается. В данном вопросе я не вижу какой либо попытки самостоятельно решить вопрос.

Comment: Да я пытался убирать всякие прозрачности, расположение элемента, фиксировал и убирал ее, все это через стили пытался сделать. А как это технически сделать? Про убрать класс с кнопки?

Comment: У вас `bootstrap` подключается аж 3 раза, при этом разных версий, а так как для модалки используется именно бутстрап, то это в теории может быть проблемой. Видно, что при нажатии появляется два `<div class="modal-backdrop fade show"></div>`. Помимо этого в обработчике формы для закрытия модалки использовать `$('#exampleModal').modal('hide');` вместе с `setTimeout` вместо `loader.fadeOut`

Comment: Спасибо, пороюсь в стилях..